# Escaped apostrophe in notifications

Tags: bug, status-completed

The badge notification seems to have an encoded apostrophe in it. Interestingly the notification of reputation change for the same question doesn't seem to have a problem.

[image]

I've seen this on safari for iPad and Chrome for the PC if that makes any difference.

Comment: Have you considered putting a free hand circle around the relevant part of the image?

Comment: @githubphagocyte done - I was on my pad earlier so it wasn't easy

Comment: I don't have any recent badges on questions with apostrophes to check if I can replicate this, but have you tried anything other than Safari for iPad? It might be safari's fault and I can't install safari to check atm. If anyone else sees the same it would be good to post their screenies as well. Also, isn't this better suited for meta.stackexchange?

Comment: @ivy_lynx it's also an issue on chrome on the PC so I doubt it. Probably, this is where I spotted it ;-)

Comment: @Liath y u no say so in post? In any case, we need to find out if this is WB.SE specific or a wider issue.

Comment: @ivy_lynx updated - I've also not seen it on any other SE site yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Should be fixed now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242036/155160).

Comment: It is indeed fixed!